# Run background jobs with elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, config, web-worker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to start a background job in elastic beanstalk, the background job has an infinite loop so it never returns a response and so I receive this error:" Some instances have not responded to commands.Responses were not received from [i-ba5fb2f7]."

I am starting the background job in the elastic beanstalk .config file like this:
  06_start_workers:
    command: "./workers.py &"

Is there any way to do this? I don't want elastic beanstalk to wait for a return value of that process ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed it, just needed to write this command instead:

> `command: "nohup ./workers.py > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &"`

Comment: what happens when you deploy your app again? will the old worker be terminated? otherwise you will have multiple worker processes

Comment: @linqu it doesn't :( Every time I deploy something new, it creates a new nohup process :(